# Installed .deb package won't run because there's a snap version of the package with the same name

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, snap, deb

I installed bbk-cli from the .deb package

```
eddie@laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'bbk-cli' instead of './bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bbk-cli
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/209 kB of archives.
After this operation, 503 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/eddie/Downloads/bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb bbk-cli amd64 1.0.0 [209 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package bbk-cli.
(Reading database ... 292678 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bbk-cli (1.0.0) ...
Setting up bbk-cli (1.0.0) ...
```

So it installed correctly from what I can tell. However when I try to run it, this happens

```
eddie@laptop:~/Downloads$ bbk-cli

Command 'bbk-cli' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install bbk-cli
```

I understand that I could remove it and install it via the snap, but is there a way to **not use the snap but run it from the already installed package?**

EDIT: *I also tried installing using dpkg with the same result*

```
eddie@laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i ./bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package bbk-cli.
(Reading database ... 292678 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bbk-cli (1.0.0) ...
Setting up bbk-cli (1.0.0) ...
eddie@laptop:~/Downloads$ bbk-cli

Command 'bbk-cli' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install bbk-cli
```

EDIT II at the request of @user535733:

```
eddie@laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -l bbk-cli
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-======================================
ii  bbk-cli        1.0.0        amd64        Measurement client for Bredbandskollen
```

Comment: There is no bbk-cli in Ubuntu's apt repositories. Contact with the author of this package.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański I downloaded the .deb file myself and didn't use a repository... I get the same result if I use dpkg to install it

Comment: Not all .deb files in the internet work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Rather open Nautilus, navigate to the .deb file, right click on it and open with Software Install.

Comment: Edit your question to provide a complete listing of the files contained within the package: `dpkg -L bbk-cli`

Comment: Well that the .deb file is called `bbk-cli_1.0.0_amd64.deb` you must run it with `bbk_cli`

Comment: @Raffles how does a user know what the command will be based on the .deb?

Comment: Wrong output. We need to see `dpkg -L` (uppercase). You provided `dpkg -l` (lowercase). They do different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just downloaded the `.deb` file from [this website](https://www.bredbandskollen.se/bredbandskollen-cli/) into a new folder `bbk_cli` in the home directory

I then opened Nautilus, went to the `bbk_cli` folder, right clicked and selected "Open with Software Install", entered my password and it installed with no problem.

Then I typed `bbk_cli` in a terminal and this is the output (please note the underscore is **not** the same as a minus sign)

```
raffles@raffles-MS-7917:~$ bbk_cli
Start: 2022-07-17 18:36:40
Network operator: GVA-Canalbox
Support ID: mmo207d12952
Latency:     178.777 ms
Download:     15.073 Mbit/s
Upload:       14.868 Mbit/s
Measurement ID: 417725462
```

I don't like snaps and will update why shortly.

This video will give you an insight into Snaps [Switched to Linux](https://yewtu.be/watch?v=NE-AdmDGkEk)

Comment: After following your seteps I am actually getting the same error `$ bbk-cli

Command 'bbk-cli' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install bbk-cli`

Comment: You must use `bbk_cli` to run it, not `bbk-cli` note the underscore in the first option works and not the minus sign

Comment: that absolutely worked. Thank you! So I understand better, how did you know that you needed the underscore and not the hypen? @mook765

Comment: All credit for that goes to @mook765 and if mook765 submits it as an answer I will upvote it too.

Answer (score 12):

You installed some `bbk-cli` package, and appear to expect that that will give you an executable of the same name, installed in one of the directories of your path. That is not necessarily the case, and in this case, that indeed does not happen.

The symptoms you describe indicate that

1. The package you downloaded from some unspecified source indeed installs correctly
2. The package does not install an executable `bbi-cli`.

   What the name of the executable is, that is something you will need to find out from the documentation. Alternatively, the command `dpkg -L bbi-cli` will list all the installed files. Files installed in directories in the system path, typically `/usr/bin`, but could also be elsewhere, are executables you can run by typing their name on the command line.